# How can I add DataTables plugin to table created with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I create a table by reading the data from my database and it displays it correctly but when I want to add the DataTables plugin it doesnt work.

This is what I tried:

```
<?php
include_once 'classes/baza.class.php';
include_once 'classes/prijava_odjava.class.php';

$naziv = "Ispis";
include '_header.php'
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   



<nav class="large-6 row">
    <table id='tablica'>  
        <?php
        $baza = new Baza();

        $upit = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $rezultat = $baza->selectDB($upit);


        //echo "";
        echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Korisničko ime</th><th>Lozinka</th><th>Email</th><th>Last update</th><th>Aktivacijski kod</th><th>Aktiviran</th></tr>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id_user']
            . "</td><td> " . $row['username']
            . "</td><td> " . $row["password"]
            . "</td><td> " . $row["email"]
            . "</td><td> " . $row['last_update']
            . "</td><td> " . $row['aktivacijski_kod']
            . "</td><td> " . $row['aktiviran']
            . "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }

        //echo ""; //Close the table in HTML
        ?>
    </table>
</nav>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tablica").DataTable({
        "bSort": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": true
    });
});
</script>

<?php include '_footer.php'; ?>
```

This code still shows the data from the database but it doesn't use the DataTable plugin. Its like it even isn't there.

EDIT:
Added thead and tbody but I have the same problem.

```
echo "<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Korisničko ime</th><th>Lozinka</th><th>Email</th><th>Last update</th><th>Aktivacijski kod</th><th>Aktiviran</th></tr></thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id_user']
                . "</td><td> " . $row['username']
                . "</td><td> " . $row["password"]
                . "</td><td> " . $row["email"]
                . "</td><td> " . $row['last_update']
                . "</td><td> " . $row['aktivacijski_kod']
                . "</td><td> " . $row['aktiviran']
                . "</td></tr>";
            }

            echo "</tbody>";
```

Comment: Seems to me like you need to follow a tutorial:[http://phpflow.com/php/datatables-example-server-side-processing-with-php/](http://phpflow.com/php/datatables-example-server-side-processing-with-php/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://datatables.net/manual/installation

> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be
>   valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a body (tbody).
>   An optional footer (tfoot) can also be used.

You must update your html with a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`

Comment: Added them to the code but the same thing happens edited the question so you can see how I added them

Comment: Check in console if you have errors. (Ex for chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console )